# "Поллитровый" и "поллитровка" — через дефис или нет?

Tags: слитно-дефис

На [этом](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/orfografiya/pravopisanie/pol-litra-ili-pollitra.html) сайте считают, что оба слова пишутся слитно:

> Обратим внимание на слитное написание однокоренных слов «поллитровка» и «поллитровый».

У [Аванесова](http://povto.ru/russkie/slovari/orfoepicheskie/avanesov/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0415.htm) же видим дефисное *"пол-литровый"* и слитное *"поллитровка".*

На кого ориентироваться, на Аванесова? Или будут разные мнения?

Answer (score 2):

Ориентироваться, видимо, следует на  **справочник**  Лопатина.

Через дефис пишутся сложные прилагательные, образованные от сложных существительных, пишущихся через дефис:
пол-литра - пол-литровый.

http://orthographia.ru/orf.php?paragraph=pp129.php

Comment: Правда, здесь нормативное пол-литра как мера, а если это разговорное сущ. жен. рода "поллитра" = поллитровка, то пишется слитно: Без поллитры не разобраться.

Comment: У Кузнецова и в значении бутылки "пол-литра" тоже через дефис.

Comment: Просторечия трудно подвести под общее правило, слитное написание приводится в Словаре синонимов русского языка :: https://gufo.me/dict/synonyms/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0, в словаре галлицизмов https://gallicismes.academic.ru/30483/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0, в Большом словаре русских поговорок. У Астафьева:

И вот на тебе - враг на Волге, под Москвой, под Ленинградом, половины страны и армии как корова языком слизнула, кто кого доламывает - попробуй разберись без поллитры. В. Астафьев Прокляты и убиты. // НМ 1992 10 68.

Comment: Да, действительно нестыковка в словарях.

Comment: Людмила. Там  более недоразумение, чем нестыковка. "Поллитра" просто используется двояко. если "поллитра" - просто мера жидкости (склоняется как "полметра"), то это обычное правило: пишется через дефис. А вот "поллитре" в значении "бутылка-поллитровка" ("поллитру съел") некоторые словари просто по непонятным причинам отказывают в праве на существование. Это именно недоразумения, противоречия тут нет.

Answer (score 1):

> На этом сайте считают, что оба слова пишутся слитно:

Источник доверия не заслуживает, прямо скажем. Другое дело, что Аванесов - тоже так себе авторитет по части орфографии. Он орфоэпист, а это совсем другое. Но в данном случае Аванесов прав, давая дефисное написание.

На самом деле вопрос восходит к попыткам Орфографической Комиссии навести хоть какой-то порядок в написании этих слов, вылившихся в предложения 2002 г., которые только ленивый еще не насекомил.

Согласно основному правилу слова с компонентом "пол-" перед основой, начинающейся с "л", пишутся через дефис. Правило, прямо скажем, апеллирует более к традиции, чем к логике.

Согласно негласному основному исключению, слова с "пол-", потерявшие прямую семантическую связь с "половиной", основному правилу не подчинятся, отсюда "поллитровка". На основании этого и была предпринята попытка нормировать написание "поллитровый". Попытка эта застряла ещё на подходе к окончательной редакции предложений, которые, собственно, тоже были реализованы лишь в отдельных положениях.

Наконец, есть еще дополнительное "исключение из исключения". "Пол-литровый" считается (по Лопатину) разговорным вариантом к "полулитровый", а написание подобных формм не всегда регулируется основными правилами и "основными исключениям", чаще его оговаривают особо. Для "поллитровый" никаких оговорок за всю историю этого слова сделано не было. Это, видимо, и послужило отказом в признании формы  "поллитровый" нормативной.

Авторы с того сайта, похоже, слышали звон, да не знали откуда.

Добавлю, что Ожегов дает "поллитра" как разговорный вариант к "поллулитра" в статье пол-литра, не оговаривая даже, что речь идет о специфическом значении "термина". Чем и добавляет путаницы.

Но по вопросу ***"пол-литра"*** все авторитетные источники едины. Только дефисное написание.

---

Тут возник оффтоп по поводу статуса ОК.

Нету у неё полномочий "регулировать нормы русского языка". Их нет даже у ИРЯ РАН.
ОК создавалась и существует для выработки **предложений** в части орфографии. Никаких официальных функций регулирования "норм русского языка" у неё нет и не было. Даже её основные предложения по части уточнения орфографии (какое там регулирование норм!) не нашли и не были приняты сообществом. Sapienti Sat, как говорится.

Есть только одна страна в мире, где нормы языка (и то с некоторыми ограничениями) регулируются специальным органом. Это Израиль. Но там это объясняется тем, что искусственно возрожденный иврит просто не мог выработать единой модели для своего развития. Институт Иврита по сути дела просто выбирает одну из возможностей, предоставляемых языком. И своим именем закрепляет её как нормативную.

====
UPD

оффтоп-2.
Это становится уже несколько смешным, но добавлю про Украину.
В Украине есть Комиссия по вопросам правописания ("Комісія з питань правопису"), у которой примерно тот же статус, что и у российской ОК, даже ниже. Грубо говоря - никакого официального статуса по части **регулирования норм** языка там нет и быть не может.

В постановлении Кабмина о её создании от 19 февраля 2002 о функциях и полномочиях комиссии вообще ничего не сказано.

https://zakon1.rada.gov.ua/cgi-bin/laws/main.cgi?nreg=198-2002-%EF

Даже сама подготовка новой редакции правил правописания возложена не на комиссию, а на АН Украины. Ну о чем тут еще можно спорить-то?!

Comment: Выходит, что - "без поллитра хрен проссышь" - пишется без дефиса.

Comment: Минусуют, видимо те, кому больше нечем аргументировать.

Comment: @EugeneKartoyev Вот это спорно. "Без поллитры" - точно. А что касается "Без поллитра" - то тут можно и так толковать и эдак. В целом словари против слитного написания.

Comment: @EugeneKartoyev *Минусуют, видимо те, кому больше нечем аргументировать* - да нет, это один товарищ никак не может усвоить, что минусовать исключительно по принципу "сам дурак" - не слишком достойное занятие. Впрочем, обсуждать это в комментариях все равно не стоит.

Comment: Не только одна страна. В Украине - утверждает Кабинет Министров. А в России никто не может, так что ли?

Comment: * В Украине - утверждает Кабинет Министров*  что именно утверждает? Номы языка? Вы, простите, совсем уже вопросом не владеете. И что значит "не только одна"?

Comment: *А в России никто не может, так что ли?* - простите, смысл вопроса до меня не доходит.

Comment: Да-да. Нова редакція українського правопису 2019 - издана Кабинетом Министров и обязательна во всех учебных заведениях. А там много бредовых изменений. А в русском никто не может менять "академические" нормы? По крайней мере, так утверждаете только вы.

Comment: Простите, я не могу это комментировать. Не компетентен. Знаю, что в русских российских учебниках тоже есть упоминания о каких-то рекомендациях. И что?  Не могли бы вы свои мысли высказывать более понятно? И какое вообще это имеет отношение к сказанному мной?

Comment: Про украинское правописание я готов ответить в меру своего знания, но наверное, не здесь?!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100127/discussion-between-behemothus-and-oleedd).

Answer (score 0):

**пол-литра, пол-литровый** - в толковом словаре Кузнецова.

А **поллитровка** в нём же - вместе. Думаю, так как это единое понятие, а не качество.

Нужно больше верить словарям, а не сайтам, которым свойственно иногда ошибаться.

К тому же, "пол-литровый" через дефис и в словаре Лопатина, экс-председателя Орфографической комиссии РАН, которая официально уполномочена регулировать нормы русского языка.
https://slovar.cc/rus/lopatin/1047449.html

Comment: Можете документ показать на официальные полномочия???

Comment: Подавайте им официальный запрос: http://orth-com.tilda.ws/ Такие документы в общий доступ не попадают.

Comment: Зачем мне-то подавать, если я официально знаю, что вы сознательно вводите в заблуждение читающего.

Comment: Ну так вы же не верите в то, что указано у них на сайте.

Comment: Я **вам** не верю. А вы документа не можете показать.

Comment: Официально уполномочена = действует по госинструкции, а не сама по себе. Вам РАН о чём-то говорит?

Comment: Понятия не имею. По мне, так если официально уполномочена, то значит есть документ, где эти полномочия четко прописаны. Документа у вас, понятно, нет. А домыслы в расчет не принимаются.

Comment: Документ-то точно есть. Любая госкомиссия создаётся и действует на законных основаниях, и её права и возможности чётко определены. Но только некоторые документы сливают в интернет. Не официально уполномоченными являются общественные организации и т.п.

Comment: Документ ест. А полномочий таких там нету. Да дело не в этом. Вы (для солидности, что ли?) внесли в ответ весьма обязывающую информацию, которые никаким образом не можете подтвердить. Остальное - в тексте моего ответа.

Comment: В задачи комиссии входит обсуждение актуальных вопросов русского правописания; оценка орфографических новаций и **принятие решений по конкретным вопросам, связанным с орфографической кодификацией и упорядочением письма**; обсуждение и **утверждение к печати** очередных изданий правил орфографии и пунктуации и академического орфографического словаря. — А в справочник-то вносят изменения. Справочник Лопатина отменил некоторые правила 1956 года. Это и есть полномочия регулировать нормы, особенно спорные моменты.

Comment: Вот так и пишите. А то "регулирование норм".

Comment: То есть изменение слитного написания на "лиро-эпический" нельзя назвать регулированием норм?

Comment: Я, простите, не успеваю за полетом вашей мысли. Я вам вашими же словами отвечу. Спросите у комиссии. )))) Я вообще про эту норму не в курсе.

Comment: Простите, я не заводил дискуссии. Я вам задал вопрос - и не получл на него внятного ответа. Из чего сделал вывод, что ваше утверждение не соответствует истине.  Это я написал в своем ответе.  "Дискуссия" - полностью ваша заслуга. У меня всё.

Comment: Мы имеем факт изменения многих слов в справочнике Лопатина. После этого не стоит сомневаться в том, что орфографическая комиссия действительно утверждает орфографические нормы. Она не существует просто так. Иначе была бы не комиссия, а общество, которое просто обсуждает и ни на что не влияет. Не вводите людей в заблуждение. Я смотрю, это ваше любимое занятие.

Comment: Уже сказал, я не могу и не ставлю себе задачей это комментировать. Уже потому, что не вижу связи ни с темой вопроса, ни с фактом вашего вброса заведомо ложной информации о статусе ОК. Да и вообще комментарии не предназначены для подобного. Простите, у меня действительно все.

Comment: Я не знаю, что там у вас получается. Вашу логику к делу не пришьешь,  да и не хочу я в ней разбираться. Статус ОК я бы определил как совещательный орган, поскольку иное никакими правоустанавливающими документами не подтверждено. Тут еще можно, спорить, но уж регулирующим органом ОК быть заведомо не может. Просто потому, что язык не принадлежит государству - в том смысле права собственности или какого-то другого исключительного права. И естественно регулировать нормы языка оно, государство, никак не может.

Comment: Но касательно Украины закон вам доказал. Там правила украинского языка как государственного. И с этого следует, что хоть и язык принадлежит народу, а корректировать нормы печати (в том числе орфографические) государство имеет право. А право определяется теми же законами.

Comment: @oleedd в справочнике Лопатина и приведены рекомендации.

Comment: @Aer То есть, по-вашему, те все правила можно не соблюдать? Там есть некоторые рекомендации (например, касательно буквы Ё) - тогда там так и пишется: рекомендуется...

Comment: @oleedd см. текст предисловия к ПАС. Официльно утвержденные нормы — это только лишь "Правила" 1956 г. ПАС как бы "уточняет" нормы, но на самом деле __не__ является _новым_ перечнем норм.

Comment: @Aer я влезу с последней репликой, ок? Тут вся полемика возникла не по причине спорного отношения к термину рекомендация, а в результате подмены терминологии. "Регулирование норм языка" предполагает наличие какого-то глобального регулирующего органа, причем для языка вообще, а дело Орфографической комиссии - это именно рекомендации, никаким законом иное не прописано. Справочники и все прочее - глубоко частное дело на фоне подобной подмены. Ну и "официально утвержденные" тоже вызывает сомнения в трактовке даже по отношению к П-56.

Comment: @behemothus да, но давайте не будем "оставлять последнее слово" за собой в отсутствие другого участника дискуссии. Поставим пока многоточие.

Comment: Простите, я попросил последнее слово исключительно после вашего замечания о недопустимости дискуссий. )))  Ничего более не имел в виду.